# How do I change the flashvars using the ContentScript of a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, flash

I want to create a chrome extension to help me debug my swf, and I'd like the extension to be able to change some of the flashvars while keeping others untouched.

I can't imagine this is a new or unique problem, so before I reinvent the wheel, I'm asking if anyone here has examples of it being done, or how to do it.

I've tried searching, but my googlefu seems to be off.

My use case is as follows.  I have a Google Chrome extension which has a few drop down menus with possible flash var values.  I want the change the values in the drop down, and then reload the swf with these new flashvars, but without changing flashvars which are not in my drop down menus.

I'm able to easily inject a new swf on the page with the values from my dropdown menus, however I'd like to be able to reload, rather than recreate, the swf.

I have tried using Jquery to pull all the flash vars like this:

```
var flashVars = $("param[name=flashvars]", gameSwfContainer).val();
```

However, I'm having a hard time changing or replacing just a couple of the values, and then injecting them back into the object. (Regex might be helpful here unless there is a better way?)

Thanks for your help.

Currently, I am trying to do the following, but I'm not sure if it's the right direction.
ContentScript.js

```
//Setup
var swfVersionStr = "10.1.0";
var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
var params = {};
    params.quality = "high";
    params.bgcolor = "#000000";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "game_swf_con";
    attributes.name = "game_swf_con";
    attributes.class = "game_swf_con";
    attributes.align = "middle";
var InjectedFlashvars = {
    "run_locally": "true",
        //.. some other flash vars that I won't be changing with my extension
    "swf_object_name":"game_swf"
};
// Injection code called when correct page and div detected;    
var injectScriptText = function(text)
    { 
                loopThroughLocalStorage();
                swfobject.embedSWF(
                    swfName, "game_swf_con",  
                    "760", "625", 
                    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                    InjectedFlashvars, params, attributes);
       swfobject.createCSS("#game_swf_con", "display:block;text-align:left;");
    };
        function loopThroughLocalStorage()
    {
        for(key in localStorage){
            try{
            var optionArray = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
            var option = returnSelectedFlashVar(optionArray);
            var value = option.value ? option.value : "";
            InjectedFlashvars[key] = value;
            } catch(err){}

        }
    }

    function returnSelectedFlashVar(optionArray){
        for(var i= 0; i < optionArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(optionArray[i].selected == true)
            {
                return optionArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Overall, I currently have contentscript.js, background.js, options.js, options.html, popup.html and popup.js  The code above so far only exists in contentscript.js

Comment: Share your code, will pick it up from there.

Comment: @Sudarshan Thanks I've put the code that I think might be the correct sollution, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Meh, the problem with my proposed sollution is that I need the list of flashvars that won't be changing to be defined in the htmltemplate of the project and not in the contentScript.js :(
Which means I don't have access to it in the chrome extension.

Comment: Do you mean you want to communicate from content script to chrome html? Is the script you added to question content script?

Comment: Yes, the above code is in the content script.  I just saw that I can't read localStorage from contentScript so I'm also now adding a background.js

Comment: @Sudarshan That being said, I'm willing to restructure my code so that it's done more properly.

Comment: If your intention is about communicating from content script to background script, i can share some related code; But can you explain me clearly your **complete** functionality requirement.

Comment: @Sudarshan I want to change the flashvars on the debug page that is produced by flashbuilder using the chrome extension.  I need to be able to read flashvars from various staging environments and test them locally.

Comment: Is your problem that the flashvars attribute contains a query like string that list multiple keys and their values and you want to get those as an object then add or delete values from that object and then turn that object back into the query like string?  If so, say so and Ive got some code for that.  If not, Im having a little hard time figuring exactly what needs solving.

Comment: @PAEz That could be my question. I'm looking for the best practice to change the flash vars and reload the swf using a chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a little trouble deciding what you actually wanted.
But if its manipulating the values in the flashvar maybe this will help...

```
queryToObject = function(queryString) {
    var jsonObj = {};
    var e, a = /\+/g,
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        d = function(s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " "));
        };

    while(e = r.exec(queryString)) {
        jsonObj[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
    }

    return jsonObj;
}

objectToQuery = function(object) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object),
        key;
    var value, query = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        key = keys[i];
        value = object[key];
        query += (query.length > 0 ? '&' : '') + key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    return query;
}

// this is what a flashvar value looks like according to this page...http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/flash/actionscript/flashvars.html
var testQuery = 'myvar1=value1&myvar2=value2&myvar3=a+space';

var testObject = queryToObject(testQuery);

console.debug(testObject);

testQuery = objectToQuery(testObject);

console.debug(testQuery);

testObject.myvar0 = 'bleh';

delete testObject.myvar2;

console.debug(objectToQuery(testObject));
```

And if your using localStorage in a content script then be aware that the storage will be held in the context of the page.
Try looking at [chrome.storage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) instead.

**EDIT : Answer to comments**
`This looks correct, but how do I "reload" the object so that those new flashvars are the ones that are used by the swf?`

Ive never used swfObject (havent done any flash stuff in like 5 years) but had a look and it looks like you can just rerun the `swfobject.embedSWF` with the new flashVars and it will replace the old object with the new one.  Which is fine if your replacing one that you added yourself as you can supply all of the details, if your replacing something put there by someone else you could clone the object, change some stuff and replace the original with the clone.  Cloning will not clone any events attached to the element but I dont think thats a problem in your case.  Here's an example (which I couldnt test as I couldnt find any simple sample swf that just prints the flashvars)....

```
var target = document.querySelector('#game_swf_con');
// Cloning the element will not clone any event listners attached to this element, but I dont think that's a prob for you
var clone = target.cloneNode(true);
var flashvarsAttribute = clone.querySelector('param[name=FlashVars]');
if (flashvarsAttribute) {
    var flashvars = flashvarsAttribute.value;
    flashvars = queryToObject(flashvars);
    // add a new value
    flashvars.newValue = "something";
    // update the clone with the new FlashVars
    flashvarsAttribute.value = objectToQuery(flashvars);
    // replace the original object with the clone
    target.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, target);
}​
```

Comment: Looks like we are in a cut throat competition :D

Comment: @Sudarshan hehe, no were not ;)  You can always have the points I really dont care.  So, have a look at that page I linked to and relook at your query.  It should be more like `document.querySelector('param[name=FlashVars]').value`.  Notice Ive got value on the end, becuase I think (wish he was more clear) hes trying to change the value of these elements.  Feel free to combine my answer with that selector into your answer and Ill happily delete my answer.

Comment: @Sudarshan Oh just noticed on this page.. http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/index.html .. that your selector looks right for embeds and mine for objects.  and for embeds you get the value from the FlashVars attribute.....Im a little confused from that page tho.

Comment: @Sudarshan and this site http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html confirms it on the selector thing.  Their going to need two, one for embeds (which are now obsolete according to that page) and one for objects.

Comment: The adobe link is really helpful, let us wait for Avik what he really needs :) ..

Comment: This looks correct, but how do I "reload" the object so that those new flashvars are the ones that are used by the swf?

Comment: @Avik Oh, and you might have just been able to change the data attribute of the object, but I cant test that so I just went with what I knew would cause a reload.

Comment: Perfect, that clone feature is what I didn't know about that I needed to know about :)

Comment: Blarg, now the SOL won't flush... I assume this is some wierd security domain issue with the contentscript?

Comment: @Avik any chance you could set up a test page somewhere with a simple flash file that just prints the flashvars and Ill see what I can do.  Without something to test against its a little difficult.  And please keep it light, Im on dialup.

Comment: @PAEz  here http://www.daganev.com/test/ErrorSwf.swf?var1=hellooooooonurse&var2=%22stop%20That!%22   guess that took more than 10 minutes :(

Comment: @PAEz I added shared data object to it so you can see if the content script affects that or not. It should be the last line of the text field.

Comment: @Avik what do you mean the SOL wont flush?  the vars changed so im not sure what your going on about ;)

Comment: SOL are also known as "flash cookies" or "shared objects", I added a line to verify that it's working in the print out.

Comment: @Avik  Well thats going way off topic and sounds like a flash thing that I really cant be bothered learning.  Maybe you could use this to get rid of them from JS when you need to.... http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/07/swf-for-javascript-cross-domain-flash-cookies/ ...need anymore help with that then I suggest starting a new question.

Comment: @PAEz yep, I need to look into the issue more, it's likely a new question.  Need someone who knows both Flash and chrome extensions well.  Thanks for your help, this was great.

Answer (score 0):

*Sources:*

a) [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

b) [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)

c) [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

d) [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

e) [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)

f)  [API()'s](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html)

Assuming a html page containing following code

```
<embed src="uploadify.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550"
height="400" name="myFlashMovie" FlashVars="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye"
align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash" />
```

I try to get following get height of embed object and change it.

**Sample Demonstration**

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Flash Vars",
"description":"This demonstrates Flash Vars",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1",
"permissions":["<all_urls>"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
       ]
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
// Fetches Current Width
width = document.querySelector("embed[flashvars]:not([flashvars=''])").width;
console.log("Width is  " + width);

// Passing width to background.js
chrome.extension.sendMessage(width);

//Performing some trivial calcualtions
width = width + 10;

//Modifying parameters
document.querySelector("embed[flashvars]:not([flashvars=''])").width = width;
```

**background.js**

```
//Event Handler for catching messages from content script(s)
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Width recieved is " + message);
});
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This looks handy, I think. But I want to change a specific item within the flashvars, not a basic param like the width.  For example, I would want to change "myVariable" to "goodbyeWorld" without altering the value of "mySecondVariable"